# Can I implement an implicit 'conversion' from string to boolean in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, extension-methods, implicit-conversion

There's any way to implement an **implicit** conversion from `string` to `bool` using C#?

E.g. I have the string `str` with value *Y* and when I try convert (cast) to `boolean` it must return `true`.

Comment: `bool b = str == "Y";`

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova, no! I mean: when I do bool b = (boolean) str;

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: There is a Boolean.Parse(myString) and Boolean.TryParse(myString) but only work if the string is "True" or "False"

Comment: Try to replace your string before it's checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You can't create user-defined conversions which don't convert either to or from the type they're declared in.

The closest you could easily come would be an extension method, e.g.

```
public static bool ToBoolean(this string text)
{
    return text == "Y"; // Or whatever
}
```

You could then use:

```
bool result = text.ToBoolean();
```

But you can't make this an implicit conversion - and even if you *could*, I'd advise you not to for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an extension method that you can use for any string.

```
public static bool ToBoolean(this string input)
{
    var stringTrueValues = new[] { "true", "ok", "yes", "1", "y" };
    return stringTrueValues.Contains(input.ToLower());
}
```

Here is an example of using this extension method:

```
Console.WriteLine("y".ToBoolean());
```

The result will be `True`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make the method on you own. There is no way to just cast a string to a bool. You'll end up with true if the string is not null, I believe. Just make a Boolean method that returns true if the string it's passed is y or false otherwise